# Incorrect syntax near 'XML'. for select query

Tags: sql-server-2008

My Tables :

[image]

[image]

From the Above tables I want to Query Select Statements Something like this :

```
Version ControlTestID                       TestPCID

02175bd8-69b5-4171-a9b6-f0e46ce6eb05        703A,703B,704A,704B
cdff4816-9217-4dba-a608-4247964a14bc        BM002,BM003,BM004
```

Should display  like the above format...

I am using the Following Query :

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE(TESTERID VARCHAR(1000),VER_CONTROL_TESTID VARCHAR(1000))
declare @ColumnNameList nvarchar(1000),@ColumnNameList1 nvarchar(1000)   

SELECT @ColumnNameList = coalesce(@ColumnNameList + ',' + TEST_DESCRIPTION, TEST_DESCRIPTION),
@ColumnNameList1=VER_CONTROL_TESTID 
FROM LU_TDE_VER_CONTROL_TESTERID TESTERID  
Inner join LU_TDE_VER_CONTROL VERCTRL on VERCTRL.VER_CONTROL_ID = TESTERID.VER_CONTROL_TESTID 
INSERT INTO @TBL
SELECT @ColumnNameList ,@ColumnNameList1  
sELECT TESTTB.*,CTRL.TESTPCID,CTRL.COMPONENT,CTRL.GROUP_NAME,CTRL.VERSION_LIST FROM LU_TDE_VER_CONTROL CTRL 
inner join @TBL TESTTB on ctrl.VER_CONTROL_ID = TESTTB.VER_CONTROL_TESTID
```

the above query is working but displaying wrong results like below.:

```
             TestPCID                                    VER_CONTROL_TESTID

703A,703B,704A,704B,BM002,BM003,BM004   CDFF4816-9217-4DBA-A608-4247964A14BC
```

After that I tried another method something like this :

```
SELECT 
   SS.VER_CONTROL_ID,
   STUFF((SELECT '; ' + US.TEST_DESCRIPTION 
          FROM LU_TDE_VER_CONTROL_TESTERID US
          WHERE US.VER_CONTROL_TESTID = SS.VER_CONTROL_ID
           FOR XML PATH(''), 1, 1, '') [SECTORS/USERS]
FROM LU_TDE_VER_CONTROL SS
GROUP BY SS.VER_CONTROL_ID
```

it's throwing error like : Incorrect syntax near 'XML'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a ) after `FOR XML PATH('')`

```
SELECT 
   SS.VER_CONTROL_ID,
   STUFF((SELECT '; ' + US.TEST_DESCRIPTION 
          FROM LU_TDE_VER_CONTROL_TESTERID US
          WHERE US.VER_CONTROL_TESTID = SS.VER_CONTROL_ID
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [SECTORS/USERS]
FROM LU_TDE_VER_CONTROL SS
GROUP BY SS.VER_CONTROL_ID
```